# Retrieving count from a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of comments as a parameter to each lesson on my website. I have tried a number of different ways (shown below) to retrieve the number of comments. The structure of my Model looks like this:

```
 public class EducateLesson
{
    [Key]
    public int EducateLessonID { get; set; }

    public EducateTopics Topic { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Introduction { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string VideoURL { get; set; }

    public int Likes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public void AddComment(Comment c)
    {
        Comments.Add(c);
    }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string IdentityUserName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have noted that the Comment class has no FK to the lesson object here.

These are the methods I've tried to retrieve the count for an individual lesson in the view:

```
count = (from l in lesson.Comments select l).Count();
@lesson.Comments.Count()
@lesson.Comments.Count
```

Comment: yes number of comments per lesson object. I've created a similar method in the model to return the number of comments and that does not work.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at that

Comment: If I was in the view, that has `@model EducateLesson`, I would reference `@Model.Comments.Count` to retrieve the number of items in the Comments variable of the current views model.

Comment: See I want to access the number in this view because its a summary of the data for each lesson

Comment: If `Comment` has no FK relationship to `EducateLesson` then you cannot possibly get the comments associated with a `EducateLesson` - all you can do is get all comments. Just add the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this answer without changing the model. Comments made on this post were not actually beneficial. Firstly I added this to my repository class:

```
   public int CommentCount(int id)
    {
        EducateLesson lesson = context.EducateLessons.Find(id);
        return lesson.Comments.Count;
    }
```

Next I took the count by creating a repository class and using this method for each lesson object:

```
    int count = 0;
    EducateRepository EducateRepository = new EducateRepository();

    count = EducateRepository.CommentCount(lesson.EducateLessonID);
```